# Display arrays inside a `dash_table.DataTable` cell

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Is there a way to display arrays inside a `dash_table.DataTable` other then: [image]

As I select a cell I get the elements separated by comma. How can this be achieved as standard without having to select a cell.

[image]

Example:

```
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd


df_filter = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Filter Id': 1, 'Category': ['admission_type'], 'Element': [['URGENT', 'ELECTIVE']], 'Patients': [[43798, 40286, 44083, 43927, 10027, 10065, 10035, 42231, 10112, 10114]], 'Count': [10]})

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(id = 'table',
                                            columns = [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_filter.columns],
                                            data = df_filter.to_dict('records'))],
                      style = dict(width = '200px'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a subcolumn for each patient, @see documentation for [Multi-Headers](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/style#multi-headers)

Or if you just need the list of patients as a comma-separated string, then output it as a string, for example :

```
[ ','.join([43798, 40286]) ] # instead of [[43798, 40286]]
```

Comment: Ok thank you. Since i have Integers i used: `','.join([str(my_int) for my_int in [43798, 40286]] )`

Comment: This is just workaround. In my opinion this should be report as enhancement at github: https://github.com/plotly/dash-table