# Plotly Dash: dbc.Table not displaying list items properly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am developing a dashboard using `plotly dash`. I have a dataframe and some of its items are list of string names.

```
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe
data = {
    "A": [['a', 'm', 'n'], 'b', ['c', 'p', 'q'], 'd'],
    "B": [['a', 'm', 'n'], 'b', ['c', 'p', 'q'], 'd'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

# Print DF
           A          B
0  [a, m, n]  [a, m, n]
1          b          b
2  [c, p, q]  [c, p, q]
3          d          d
```

In `app.py`, I have dash application where I am displaying the dataframe using dash bootstrap component `Table`

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, html

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Table.from_dataframe(df)
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8001", debug=True)
    
# On Running output as below

A   B
amn amn
b   b
cpq cpq
d   d
```

The data is displayed but Issue is with items having list is not displayed properly as in above output.

```
Observed Output:
amn

Excepted output
[a, m, n] or
a, m, n
```

Why `dbc.Table` not displaying list items properly. What I am missing?

Comment: See [Display arrays inside a dash_table.DataTable cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67871483/2529954). The answer should apply to `dbc.Table` as well.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks. Earlier, I also tried replacing the `dbc.Table` with `dash DataTable` but got the same result. But now this will do the trick.